# USRP on RedHawk

Tags: redhawksdr, usrp

I'm trying to use a USRP platform (B100,USRP1 or B2x0) on Redhawk.
I installed redhawk 1.9.0,uhd driver and usrp_uhd device on centOS6.5_x64, both virtual machine and native, and I made a node including USRP_UHD and GPP device, a simple component and waveform.
I would like to test simple waveform on my previous node but I got this error when the device manager run:

`WARN:Device_impl - Unable to connect to IDM channel
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device USRP_UHD_1 on Device
Manager uhd_node
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Initializing device USRP_UHD_1 on Device
Manager uhd_node
-- Opening a USRP1 device...
INFO:uhd_node:GPP_1:Registering Device
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device GPP_1 on Device Manager uhd_node
-- Using FPGA clock rate of 64.000000MHz...
ERROR:USRP_UHD_i - USRP COULD NOT BE INITIALIZED!
WARN:USRP_UHD_i - CAUGHT EXCEPTION WHEN INITIALIZING USRP. WAITING 1
SECOND AND TRYING AGAIN
ERROR:uhd_node:GPP_1:Could not register with DeviceManager: timeout
while attempting to register
ERROR:USRP_UHD_i - USRP COULD NOT BE INITIALIZED!
ERROR:USRP_UHD_i - Unable to initialize USRP!
ERROR:DeviceManager_impl - Device 'USRP_UHD' -
'DCE:631ec04b-1541-4992-b007-5d7c87874f5d' may not have been
configured correctly; Call to configure() resulted in
InvalidConfiguration exception
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device USRP_UHD_1 on Domain Manager
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Initializing device GPP_1 on Device Manager uhd_node
INFO:DeviceManager_impl - Registering device GPP_1 on Domain Manager`

Can anyone help me to find a solution to use a USRP on redhawk??Do anyone manage to use USRP on RedHawk?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, this usually means you didn't specify the ip address of the USRP when you put the USRP_UHD Device into the Device Manager.  If you know the ip address, then simply set the USRP_ip_address property of the Device in your Device Manager and install the Device Manager into SDRROOT again.  If you don't know the ip address of the USRP, you can try running the uhd_find_devices command.  If that command doesn't return anything, you can find the MAC Address on the back of the USRP and use it to search for the USRP on your network.  You should be able to run a command like this to find it:

sudo nmap -sP `<Your Subnet e.g 192.168.1.*`> | grep -B 3 -i `<Your MAC Address with each octet separated by a colon e.g aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff`>

Once you have that ip address, you should be able to run

uhd_usrp_probe --args="addr=`<your USRP's ip`>"

That should give you output pertaining to your USRP that will verify that you have the correct ip address.  Then you should be able to use that ip address in the USRP_ip_address property of the USRP_UHD Device.

Also note that you may get some UHD Warnings pertaining to recv and send buffer sizes.  These will suggest two commands to run that you should probably go ahead and execute.

Comment: Hi pwolfram,

unfortunately my USRP platforms are connected to my laptop by usb, therefore I don't know if it's possible to find its IP address.

Comment: Are you using a USB to ethernet converter?

Comment: No, my USRP models(B100,B2x0,1) connect to the laptop by usb directly and for this I cannot apply your solution

Comment: Ah, I was assuming the N210 model.  If you look at the init_usrp call in the USRP_UHD.cpp file, you can see that they make the assumption of using an ip address to to get a reference to the USRP.  Without the same hardware as you, I can't say for certain, but you may be able to modify the code in order to suit your needs by getting the reference to the device in a different way

Comment: This page may be helpful: http://files.ettus.com/uhd_docs/manual/html/identification.html

Comment: I took a look at the code and I'm trying to debug the code...It seems that there is no problem about the USRP address because the value of device_addr_t["addr0"]="" indicates an usb connection.

Comment: Have you been able to determine where the exception actually gets thrown?

Comment: It should be function update_myDeviceSeq in the row :
`availChan.gain_current=usrpDevice->get_rx_gain(chan);`
This is a call to virtual function of multi_usrp.hpp file installed by uhd driver and it should be the same in every systems.
I commented the lines about get_rx_gain and it seems to start but I'm not able to set the properties of my tuner.
Can you help me again please??
Thank you

Comment: Good news that it's running now!  The way the USRP_UHD Device is set up, you set the properties by allocating onto the Device.  The process isn't incredibly intuitive, although it should be easier in 1.10.  I see that you asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329993/usrp-uhd-source-and-sink-for-redhawk) question, so I'll post a step-by-step response there that should hopefully get you up and running

Comment: We'll open another post :)